# What are the differences between OAuth 2.0 and 2.1?

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth-2.1

I was just looking at [Spring Authorization Server](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server) and noticed that it mentions OAuth 2.1.

What are the differences between OAuth 2.0 and 2.1?

Comment: Read the manual https://oauth.net/2.1/

Comment: Thanks for the link! I just looked at the current draft and posted my findings as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OAuth 2.1 specification is currently in draft state. Because of that it currently not clear what will be the final differences.

See current draft: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-1-05

**Excerpt from the current draft:**

> This draft consolidates the functionality in OAuth 2.0 [RFC6749],
> OAuth 2.0 for Native Apps ([RFC8252]), Proof Key for Code Exchange
> ([RFC7636]), OAuth 2.0 for Browser-Based Apps
> ([I-D.ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps]), OAuth Security Best Current
> Practice ([I-D.ietf-oauth-security-topics]), and Bearer Token Usage
> ([RFC6750]).
>
> Where a later draft updates or obsoletes functionality found in the
> original [RFC6749], that functionality in this draft is updated with
> the normative changes described in a later draft, or removed
> entirely.
>
> A non-normative list of changes from OAuth 2.0 is listed below:
>
> - The authorization code grant is extended with the functionality
>   from PKCE ([RFC7636]) such that the default method of using the
>   authorization code grant according to this specification requires
>   the addition of the PKCE parameters
> - Redirect URIs must be compared using exact string matching as per
>   Section 4.1.3 of [I-D.ietf-oauth-security-topics]
> - The Implicit grant (response_type=token) is omitted from this
>   specification as per Section 2.1.2 of
>   [I-D.ietf-oauth-security-topics]
> - The Resource Owner Password Credentials grant is omitted from this
>   specification as per Section 2.4 of
>   [I-D.ietf-oauth-security-topics]
> - Bearer token usage omits the use of bearer tokens in the query
>   string of URIs as per Section 4.3.2 of
>   [I-D.ietf-oauth-security-topics]
> - Refresh tokens for public clients must either be sender-
>   constrained or one-time use as per Section 4.12.2 of
>   [I-D.ietf-oauth-security-topics]

See: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-1-05#section-10